# Function call only works in constructor, otherwise function spawns an invisible label

Tags: pyqt, qwidget, qlabel, qpixmap

I'm programming snake with pyqt5. Then I try to use self.spawnFruit() in the constructor everything works and i see the fruits in the Window.
But when I try to use the same function outside of **init**() nothing on the window appears.

E.g. I have a Key.Event that will call the function self.spawnFruit if I press F.

It seems that the labels are on Gui but they're invisible.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as gui
from PyQt5 import QtCore as core
import numpy as np

spielfeldgröße = 16
state = [[0 for y in range(spielfeldgröße)] for x in range(spielfeldgröße)]
size = 30#10 pixel

class GameWindow(qw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)

        self.spawnFruit() #spawns a fruit

    def spawnFruit(self):
        fruitpixmap = gui.QPixmap(size,size)
        fruitpixmap.fill(Qt.red)

        #find available spots to spawn fruits on the map
        available = list()
        for x in range(spielfeldgröße):
            for y in range(spielfeldgröße):
                if self.state[x][y] == 0:
                    available.append((x,y))

        lenght = len(available)
        rand = np.random.randint(0, lenght)

        x,y = available[rand]
        print("fruit at:", x, ":", y)
        #spawn
        label = qw.QLabel(self)
        label.setPixmap(fruitpixmap)
        label.move(x*size, y*size)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if(key == Qt.Key_F):
            self.spawnFruit() #doesn't spawns a fruit
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)


app = qw.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = GameWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Change `if(key == Qt.Key_F):` to `if (event.key() == Qt.Key_F):`

Comment: The function is called. I can see the print() in the console

Comment: I can give you the code but how?

Comment: This means usually , let you update the current code to the executable code.I can't know `size`,`spielfeldgröße` and `self.state`. If you don't want to do it, please let us know the variables.

Comment: Thanks. You will get an answer from somebody.

Comment: Updated the vars but im 99% sure that the proplem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

**Explanation**

There are some points to say, but the main problem is why new labels don't show up?

In python , with `PyQt` and `PySide`. We prepare the widgets in advance , and set them to the main widget and show them all at the last time.

If you want to add the new visible item to it, you must call clearly `setVisible(True)` respectively.

and `event.key() == Qt.Key_F:` is the idiom of keyEvents.

It is often confused.

And please warn `IndexError` of the state.
list starts from 0 ,so you often meet the `IndexError`.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import random
spielfeldgröße = 16

size = 30#10 pixel
class GameWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)
        self.state = [[0 for y in range(spielfeldgröße)] for x in range(spielfeldgröße)]
        self.spawnFruit() #spawns a fruit

    def spawnFruit(self):

        fruitpixmap = QPixmap(size,size)
        fruitpixmap.fill(Qt.red)

        #find available spots to spawn fruits on the map
        available = list()
        for x in range(spielfeldgröße-1):
            for y in range(spielfeldgröße-1):
                if self.state[x][y] == 0:
                    available.append((x,y))

        lenght = len(available)
        rand = random.randint(0, lenght - 1)

        x,y = available[rand]
        print("fruit at:", x, ":", y)
        #spawn
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setPixmap(fruitpixmap)  
        label.move(x*size, y*size)
        label.setVisible(True)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if(event.key() == Qt.Key_F):
            self.spawnFruit() #doesn't spawns a fruit
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = GameWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This problem is very easy but very difficult to be aware of.It will be often a waste of time.to put Question was very good.